# How to change the Image of the image button dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, imagebutton

I have two set of Images being displayed on ImageButtons and I am changing the images by setting them dynamically. 
but the new/ changed image is not reflected on screen. I believe it has something to do with refreshing the screen after setting the image. 
can anyone help me how the image on a imagebutton can be changed dynamically and displayed?

--Thanks in advance

Comment: try invalidate(); on button might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Answer (score 3):

Please assign image as "background" image instead of "src" in ImageButton.

Ex:-

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/img1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_yes" />
```

And In codding side dynamically update as below.

```
img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use invalidate() or postInvalidate() depends whether or not you are in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

No need to refresh. From my point of view, like pagination, if you click next button for that button's event handling just replace the drawable resource what you want to put. What I understand from your requirement. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I am replacing the drawable resource but it image is not getting replaced.

Comment: Where did you put? Just specifically try to mention what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by several people using validate or postvalidate works for me in all contexts.

However it sounds as if Android's LevelListDrawable resource is a more appropriate option for you - this allows you to select which image is being displayed from a list of images using a simple SetImagelevel call on the imageview.